# How to test individual RAM modules with memtest86?

Tags: ram, memtest, stress-testing, memory-test

I bought a used PC that is quite old and decided to test the RAM with memtest86 (ran for about 3.5 hrs) using a live USB but it seems that only one module (the first one in slot 0 which is the slower one) is tested. Since the test never finishes, how do I test the second module? Do I have to physically remove the first before testing the second module?

[image: memtest86]

Comment: What it's really telling you is that you can't mix and match RAM sticks with different speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik Memtest86 has no feature to restrict the test to a particular memory module. You need to remove all other modules to test a single specific module.

Comment: There's no "quick and dirty" way to tell if you're RAM is alright?

Comment: @H3R3T1K: "Quick and dirty" kind of defeats the purpose of an integrity check.

Comment: True. I just tested the HDD in the same PC and it's so much easier.